# Does running a project from XCode clear the file system?

Tags: swift, xcode, filesystems

I am working on a project were I am saving pictures to the file system. I have done this successfully. If I take the picture on my phone and save them to the file system then load them it loads the correct pictures. If I unplug the phone and close out the application and open it up again the pictures are still there. Everything works fine. However, if I run the project from XCode again, and I open up the app, then the pictures are gone and I get a

```
missing image at: /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/FD7ABE14-D2BF-4117-8E4E-E83052F6A088/Documents/ProfileGIFImage1
```

This path is saved in the NSUserDefaults which I know do not go away when I run the project again. 
Are these pictures being deleted? Are the being moved? Why are thing not there any more?

Answer (score 0):

It must be there but to need to wait for a second to let load your controller properly.. If you don't know how to wait ask me again..

Answer (score 0):

Running the project from XCode clears file system. Pictures will stay there and be loaded if you are using the app but not running from Xcode again.